# How to disable dates before today in jquery UI datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am making a hotel reservation system i have to disable past dates in jQuery UI datepicker 
here's the code

calling in .cs

```
   public class CheckLookup
        {
            [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            public DateTime checkindate { get; set; }
            [DataType(DataType.Date)]
            public DateTime checkoutdate { get; set; }
        }
```

Here's the javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        function getDateYymmdd(value) {
            if (value == null)
                return null;
            return $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", value);
        }
        $('.date').each(function () {
            var minDdate = getDateYymmdd($(this).data(""));
            var maxDate = getDateYymmdd($(this).data("val-rangedate-max"));
            $(this).datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
                minDate: minDate,
                maxDate: maxDate
            });
        });
    });
```

tell me the modification to be done in this code.

Answer (score 32):

You can try this:

```
$('.date').datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

for you case:

```
$('.date').each(function () {
   var maxDate = getDateYymmdd($(this).data("val-rangedate-max"));
   $(this).datepicker({
         dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
         minDate: 0,
         maxDate: maxDate
   });
});
```

Comment: Its working great man 
but formet is changing automaticly from dd-mm-yy to mm-dd-yy

Comment: @SahilPopli I think dateFormat should not change, see here http://jsbin.com/ecome/25/edit

Comment: hey i have done it i need one more favor i want that if i set checkin date 
20-08-2012 the 2nd date picker set from 21-8-2012 how to do this tell  plz