# disable dates before yesterday when using bootstrap datepicker in laravel 4

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4, datepicker

i currently have a input type that accepts date. In the front end, i wanted that the user cannot chose dates that is before today. i already have a backend validation using laravel's `after:date` validation but i also wanted that in the front end, the user wont be able tp choose dates before the current date. In my form i have this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('ddate', 'Expected Delivery Date') }}
    {{ Form::input('date', 'date', Input::old('date'), ['class'=>'datepicker', 'placeholder' => 'Date']) }}<span class="errmsg" style="color:red"><i>{{ $errors->first('date', ':message') }}</i></span>
  </div>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Possible question already answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115981/how-to-disable-dates-before-today-in-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: thanks will check it out!

Comment: Here is another topic about Bootstrap datepicker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933173/how-to-restrict-the-selectable-date-ranges-in-bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check this solution [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/vj77M/131/) for the code demo.

```
var dateobj = new Date(); //Get today's date
var yesterday = new Date(dateobj.getFullYear(), dateobj.getMonth(), dateobj.getDay() - 2);
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    startDate: yesterday,
});
```