# disabling date in two datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

i am using two date section for Check-in and check-out respectively. i have disabled the dates before the current date in check-in section by

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker,#datepicker1" ).datepicker({
        minDate:new Date()
    });
});
</script>
```

how to disable the current date in check-out.
for example, today is 17-05-2016. all the dates before and including 17-05-2016 should be disabled

Comment: Instead of disabling, another alternative is to have a JavaScript check that the `check-out` date is after `check-in` date, before submitting the request, because at the server side, you will have to implement the same check.

Comment: Also, check this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115981/how-to-disable-dates-before-today-in-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: Well with regards to the `minDate` instead of passing the `new Date()` declaration just pass `1` through instead to indicate that the minDate is one day from today (commonly known as tomorrow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want to use the current date, you'll likely want to create a reference for tomorrow to use to initialize your date pickers :

```
// Get tomorrow 
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(new Date().getDate()+1);
```

As far as the logic you need, you could consider updating the `minDate` attribute for your "check-out" picker as the value is changed within "check-in" using the [`onSelect()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) function :

```
// Get tomorrow 
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(new Date().getDate()+1);
// Set up your datepickers
$( "#check-in" ).datepicker({
    minDate: tomorrow,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        // Get the selected date
        var inDate = new Date($(this).val());
        // Set the minimum date for the check out option to the selected date
        $("#out").datepicker('option', 'minDate',inDate);
    }
});
$('#check-out').datepicker({
    minDate: tomorrow 
});
```

**Example**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Check In</th>
      <th>Check Out</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id='in' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id='out' />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <script>
    $(function() {
      // Get tomorrow 
      var tomorrow = new Date();
      tomorrow.setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1);

      $("#in").datepicker({
        minDate: tomorrow,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
          // Get the selected date
          var inDate = new Date($(this).val());
          $("#out").datepicker('option', 'minDate', inDate);
        }
      });
      $('#out').datepicker({
        minDate: tomorrow
      })
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```